# Disable cron on a Jenkinsfile pipeline

Tags: windows, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile pipeline with a simple cron that run it every hour ( on windows env )
Now at some point I was to disable this cron for a while and after that make it work again.
Is there an easy way to do that without disabling the job ?

Answer (score 0):

Declarative pipeline has triggers directive, one uses it like this:

triggers { cron('H 4/* 0 0 1-5') }

this can be passed in the environment block of the pipeline.